# MySQL - Foreign key on delete cascade - Is there a defined execution order?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL - CASCADE ON DELETE rules on multiple tables. Obviously the execution order of "CASCADE ON DELETE"-rules depends on their order of definition.

**But is this execution order well defined or depends it on the MySQL-Version?**

Here is my simple example for three tables "A", "B", "C"

```
create table `A` (`id` NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL)  ENGINE=INNODB;
create table `B` (`id` NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL, `a_id`  NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL) ENGINE=INNODB;
create table `C` (`id` NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL, `a_id`  NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL, `b_id` NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL) ENGINE=INNODB;

ALTER TABLE `A` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `B` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `C` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `C` ADD CONSTRAINT `C1` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `B` ADD CONSTRAINT `B1` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `C` ADD CONSTRAINT `C2` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `B` (`id`);
```

If I insert the following data:

```
INSERT INTO A (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO B (id, a_id) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO C (id, a_id, b_id) VALUES (1,1,1);
```

...and try to delete the only entry in table "A":

```
delete from A where id=1;
```

...I get the following error message:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`C`, CONSTRAINT `C2` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `B` (`id`))
```

But if I change the definition of the foreign key constraints to:

```
ALTER TABLE `C` ADD CONSTRAINT `C1` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `C` ADD CONSTRAINT `C2` FOREIGN KEY (`b_id`) REFERENCES `B` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `B` ADD CONSTRAINT `B1` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

...everything is fine...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey ..! Its true..! can any body tell me what is the reason behind it...?? I tried it sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a7d2

Comment: Landing here with the same kind of problem, but this order behavior seems to have change: on mysql 5.7.21, both attempts (setting B1 after C2 or C2 after B1) results into a `Cannot DELETE` so if the order of FK resolution is defined, then it had changed meanwhile...

Answer (score -1):

Your `ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT foreign_key FOREIGN KEY` are the same, so they cannot be the reason of the error.

(...text is removed)

---

Cannot explain that strange behavior. Can suggest a workaround:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DELETE FROM A WHERE ID=1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: But it is working fine If change the order of the foreign key statements

Comment: I explicitly do not want an ON DELETE CASCADE constraint between table "C" and TABLE "B". The only difference between the above  constraints definition is their order. The order: definition for table C, definition for table B, definition for table C does not work, the order: definition for table C, definition for table C, definition for table B does work...

Comment: Yes. It is very stange behavior. I could not suppose this. I'd write a request in bugs.mysql.com.