# MySQL (5.7.21) foreign key constraint resolution order

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've browsed the MySQL documentation, but I see no info about in which order the SQL Foreign Key constraint are executed. This is important when doing a `ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE`.

Let's take a sample script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T3;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T4;

CREATE TABLE T1 (id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE T4 (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    id_t1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT t4_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (id_t1) REFERENCES t1 (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE T2 (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    id_t1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id_t1) REFERENCES t1 (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE T3 (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    id_t1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id_t1) REFERENCES t1 (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB;

ALTER TABLE T2
    ADD COLUMN id_t4 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id_t4) REFERENCES t4 (id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE T3
    ADD COLUMN id_t4 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id_t4) REFERENCES t4 (id)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT;

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO T4 VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1);

SELECT * FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T2;
SELECT * FROM T3;
SELECT * FROM T4;

/* Delete from T4: expecting a failure because of FK Restrict, getting a failure */
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM T4;
ROLLBACK;

/* Delete from T1: expecting a success, getting a success*/
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T1;
ROLLBACK;

-- Rename the FK
ALTER TABLE T4
    DROP FOREIGN KEY t4_fk1;
ALTER TABLE T4
    ADD CONSTRAINT at4_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (id_t1) REFERENCES t1 (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE;

/* Delete from T1: expecting a success, getting a failure (order of FK resolution differ) */
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T1;
ROLLBACK;

-- Rename the FK again (so it's not a matter of FK creation order)
ALTER TABLE T4
    DROP FOREIGN KEY at4_fk1;
ALTER TABLE T4
    ADD CONSTRAINT t4_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (id_t1) REFERENCES t1 (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE;

/* Delete from T1: expecting a success, getting a success again (only a matter of FK name, not creation order) */
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T1;
ROLLBACK;
```

Here, I create 4 tables, where T1 is parent of T2, T3, T4 and T4 is parent of T2 and T3.

When deleting from T4, I obviously get an error, since T2 and T3 containts rows referencing T4 (and the FK is cascade)

When deleting from T1 on 1st try, I get a success, so it seems T2, T3, T4 data are deleted, and when T4 data are deleted, the RESTRICT constraint on T2 and T3 doesn't block (T2 T3 are empty at this point).

When deleting from T1 on 2nd try (after renaming the constraint T1-T4), I get a failure, so it seems T4 data are deleted first, and a failure occurs as T2 and T3 still contain data referencing T4 (so T4 data cannot be deleted).

When deleting from T1 on 3rd try (after renaming the constraint T1-T4 again), I get a success again, so it's not a matter of the order of the FK definitions as it [seemed to be in a previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952807/mysql-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-is-there-a-defined-execution-order).

So is there a specification about the order in which constraints (like foreign keys) are resolved in mysql? Say, if table T1 is parent of tables T2, T3, T4 then what will be the FK resolution order between the three child tables? It seems to be the alphabetical order of the FK names, but is that reliable in the future?

Comment: Here's a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890067); while for 5.7, the execution order indeed seems to depend on the foreign key names, this is undocumented, can change and has in fact already changed (5.5 behaved differently). The proper approach would be to use triggers to do the cascading.

Comment: Read all the documentation.

Comment: @Solarflare Oh, I've missed that question tho! Alright, the fact it's undocumented explains why I cannot find this in the documentation : ) (even tho I "read it all", philipxy...) Indeed, that will be a better approach to use triggers in this case. Thanks!